# Angular 9 Reloading Component on Buttonclick works only every second time

Tags: angular

In my component I manage 2 lists. A list that gets 'all' data from the server and a list that gets 'filtered' data from the server.

In this ListComponent there is a child component that takes the filter inputs and emits them back out again after processing.

The 2 different lists to be displayed are managed using *ngIf. However, when i try to 'filter' twice, on the second go i get the AllReportsList again....

I've tried several options:

- Setting a Timeout to have the filter component destroyed
- using the 'router' trick: https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/refresh-angular-component-without-navigation-148a87c2de3f
- Emitting an Event in ngOnDestroy

So far, I can't find out why i can only filter on every other button click... maybe someone can see it straight away...
I think that the issue lies in the filterComponent itself, but I'm confused.

My Code:
component.ts

```
import {Component, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Report} from '../../../models/Report';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-reports-list',
  templateUrl: './all-reports-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-reports-list.component.scss']
})
export class AllReportsListComponent implements OnInit {

  // TODO: Find a way to make this still pageable without too many changes!

  allReports: Report[];
  filterRequested = false;
  filterData;
  searchParams;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.allReports = response.listResolver.content;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  requestFilteredData($event: boolean) {
    if (this.filterRequested) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.filterRequested = false;
      }, 100);
    } else {
      this.filterRequested = $event;
    }
    console.log($event);
  }

  getFilterData($event: string) {
    this.filterData = $event;
    // console.log($event);
    console.log((atob(this.filterData)));
  }


  getParams($event: string[]) {
    this.searchParams = $event;
    console.log(this.searchParams);
  }

}
```

The HTML

```
<br>
<h2 class="text-center">View All Reports</h2>
<hr>
<br>
<app-filter-reports (filterRequested)="requestFilteredData($event)"
                    (filterData)="getFilterData($event)"
                    (searchparams)="getParams($event)"></app-filter-reports>
<br>

<app-report-list *ngIf="!filterRequested"
                 [reportList]="allReports"
                 [requestList]="'all'">
</app-report-list>
<app-report-list *ngIf="filterRequested" id="test"
                 [reportList]="allReports"
                 [requestList]="'filtered'"
                 [filterData]="filterData"
                 [searchParams]="searchParams">
</app-report-list>
```

The ListComponent's .ts:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Report} from '../../../models/Report';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {ReportService} from '../../../shared/services/report/report.service';
import {map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-list',
  templateUrl: './report-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-list.component.scss']
})
export class ReportListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {

  @Input() reportList: Report[];
  @Input() requestList: string;
  @Input() filterData?;
  @Input() searchParams?;
  @Output('stillPresent') destroyed = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  asyncReports: Observable<Report[]>;
  page = 0;
  total: number;
  loading: boolean;


  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPage(0);
    // console.log(this.searchParams);
  }

  getPage(page: number) {
    this.loading = true;
    if (this.requestList === 'all') {
      // console.log('calling service');
      this.asyncReports = this.reportService.getAllReports(page - 1)
        .pipe(
          tap(response => {
            this.total = response['totalElements'];
            this.page = page;
            this.loading = false;
          }), map(response => response['content'])
        );
    }
    if (this.requestList === 'filtered') {
      this.asyncReports = this.reportService.getFilteredReports(page - 1, this.filterData, this.searchParams)
        .pipe(
          tap(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.total = response['totalElements'];
            this.page = page;
            this.loading = false;
          }), map(response => response['content'])
        );
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed.emit(false);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log('changes: ', changes);
  }

}
```

The HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="requestList === 'all'">
  <div *ngFor="let report of asyncReports | async | paginate:
  {id: 'fullList', itemsPerPage: 3, currentPage: page, totalItems: total}">
    <app-report-list-element [reportElement]="report"></app-report-list-element>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="spinner" [ngClass]="{'hidden': !loading}" ></div>
    <pagination-controls class="paginateCypru" (pageChange)="getPage($event)" id="fullList"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="requestList === 'filtered'">
  <div *ngFor="let report of asyncReports | async | paginate:
  {id: 'filteredList', itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: page, totalItems: total}">
    <app-report-list-element [reportElement]="report"></app-report-list-element>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="spinner" [ngClass]="{'hidden': !loading}" ></div>
    <pagination-controls class="paginateCypru" (pageChange)="getPage($event)" id="filteredList"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="requestList === 'parsed'">
  <div *ngFor="let report of reportList">
    <app-report-list-element [reportElement]="report"></app-report-list-element>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Filter Component's .ts:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Form, FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {ToastService} from '../../../shared/services/toast-service.service';
import {NgbDate} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-reports',
  templateUrl: './filter-reports.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-reports.component.scss']
})
export class FilterReportsComponent implements OnInit {

  // TODO: ?sort=studyNr,asc&sort=animal,desc is sort param
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  sortByForm: FormGroup;
  selectOptions: any[];

  @Output() filterRequested = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() filterData = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() searchparams = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private toastService: ToastService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      df: '',
      dt: '',
      as: '',
      a: '',
      f: '',
      r: '',
      c: '',
    });
    this.sortByForm = this.fb.group({
      sortByFirst: '',
      optionFirst: '',
      sortBySecond: '',
      optionSecond: ''
    });
    this.selectOptions = [
      {display: 'Study Number', value: 'studyNr'},
      {display: 'Date', value: 'studyDate'},
      {display: 'Active Substance', value: 'activeSubstance'},
      {display: 'Animal', value: 'animal'},
      {display: 'Formulation', value: 'formulation'},
      {display: 'Route', value: 'route'},
      {display: 'Experiment Code', value: 'code'}];
  }

  /**
   * compares the 2 dates and returns true if
   * a) only one is given
   * b) none are given
   * c) they are equal
   * d) dateFrom is before dateTo
   * @param values the object holding the dates
   */
  checkDates(values): boolean {
    if (!values.df && !values.dt) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!values.df || !values.dt) {
      return true;
    }
    const dateFrom = NgbDate.from(values.df);
    const dateTo = NgbDate.from(values.dt);
    if (!dateFrom.before(dateTo) && (!dateFrom.equals(dateTo))) {
      this.toastService.show('Date from most be before Date to!',
        {classname: 'bg-danger text-light', delay: 15000});
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {

    let values = this.searchForm.value;
    // console.log(values);
    if (!this.checkDates(values)) {
      return;
    } else {
      values = this.buildDates(values);
    }
    // console.log(values);
    if (values.r) {
      values.r = values.r.toLowerCase();
    }
    values = this.transformPresentInputsToArray(values);
    values = this.removeEmptyKeys(values);

    let options  = this.sortByForm.value;
    options = this.removeEmptyKeys(options);
    // console.log(options);
    const transmitOptions = this.generateParams(options);
    // console.log(transmitOptions);


    this.filterRequested.emit(true);
    // console.log(values);
    const json = JSON.stringify(values);
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
    this.filterData.emit(btoa(json));
    console.log(transmitOptions);
    this.searchparams.emit(transmitOptions);
    // console.log(this.sortByForm.value);
    // console.log(this.searchForm.value);
  }

  generateParams(options) {
    const transmitOptions = [];
    if (options.optionFirst && options.sortByFirst) {
      transmitOptions.push({sort: 'sort', by: options.sortByFirst + ',desc'});
    }
    if (!options.optionFirst && options.sortByFirst) {
      transmitOptions.push({sort: 'sort', by: options.sortByFirst});
    }
    if (options.optionSecond && options.sortBySecond) {
      transmitOptions.push({sort: 'sort', by: options.sortBySecond + ',desc'});
    }
    if (!options.optionSecond && options.sortBySecond) {
      transmitOptions.push({sort: 'sort', by: options.sortBySecond});
    }
    return transmitOptions;
  }

  /**
   * deletes keys that have no value from an object
   * @param obj the object holding the values
   */
  removeEmptyKeys(obj) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(key => {
      (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') && this.removeEmptyKeys(obj[key]) ||
      (obj[key] === '' || obj[key] === null) && delete obj[key];
    });
    return obj;
  }

  /**
   * checks for presence of all inputs that can be lists transforms them into arrays
   * @param values the object holding the input values
   */
  transformPresentInputsToArray(values) {
    if (values.a) {
      values.a = this.transformTextToArray(values.a);
    }
    if (values.f) {
      values.f = this.transformTextToArray(values.f);
    }
    if (values.r) {
      values.r = this.transformTextToArray(values.r);
    }
    return values;
  }

  /**
   * takes a string and splits it by ','
   * returns an array with the trimmed strings
   * @param text string to be split
   */
  transformTextToArray(text) {
    text = text.split(',');
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      text[i] = text[i].trim();
    }
    return text;
  }

  /**
   * date values must be of server requested format '01.12.2020'
   * @param values object holding the dates
   */
  buildDates(values) {

    if (!values.df && !values.dt) {
      return values;
    }
    if (values.df && values.dt) {
      let dayFrom = values.df.day;
      let monthFrom = values.df.month;
      let dayTo = values.dt.day;
      let monthTo = values.dt.month;
      if (dayFrom < 10) {
        dayFrom = '0' + dayFrom;
      }
      if (monthFrom < 10) {
        monthFrom = '0' + monthFrom;
      }
      if (dayTo < 10) {
        dayTo = '0' + dayTo;
      }
      if (monthTo < 10) {
        monthTo = '0' + monthTo;
      }
      const dateFrom = dayFrom + '.' + monthFrom + '.' + values.df.year;
      const dateTo = dayTo + '.' + monthTo + '.' + values.dt.year;
      values.df = dateFrom;
      values.dt = dateTo;
      return values;
    }
    if (values.df && !values.dt) {
      let dayFrom = values.df.day;
      let monthFrom = values.df.month;
      if (dayFrom < 10) {
        dayFrom = '0' + dayFrom;
      }
      if (monthFrom < 10) {
        monthFrom = '0' + monthFrom;
      }
      const dateFrom = dayFrom + '.' + monthFrom + '.' + values.df.year;
      values.df = dateFrom;
      return values;
    }
    if (!values.df && values.dt) {
      let dayTo = values.dt.day;
      let monthTo = values.dt.month;
      if (dayTo < 10) {
        dayTo = '0' + dayTo;
      }
      if (monthTo < 10) {
        monthTo = '0' + monthTo;
      }
      const dateTo = dayTo + '.' + monthTo + '.' + values.dt.year;
      values.dt = dateTo;
      return values;
    }


  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <h3>Filter Reports</h3>
</div>
<br>
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-left: 2em">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="df">Date from&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="df" formControlName="df" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d.toggle()"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="dt">Date to&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="dt" formControlName="dt" ngbDatepicker #dt="ngbDatepicker" (click)="dt.toggle()"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="as">Active Substance&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="as" formControlName="as"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="a">Animal&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="a" formControlName="a"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-left: 2em">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="r">Route&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="r" formControlName="r"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="f">Formulation&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="f" formControlName="f"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="c">Experiment Code&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" id="c" formControlName="c"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>
<form [formGroup]="sortByForm">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-left: 2em">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label for="foSort">Sort By</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label for="soSort">Also sort by</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-left: 2em">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select formControlName="sortByFirst" id="foSort" class="custom-select">
        <option *ngFor="let opt of selectOptions" value="{{opt.value}}">{{opt.display}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox"
             formControlName="optionFirst"
             data-onstyle="outline-warning"
             data-offstyle="outline-warning"
             data-toggle="switchbutton"
             checked data-onlabel="<img src='..\..\..\..\assets\icons\sort_decrease.png'></img>"
             data-offlabel="<img src='..\..\..\..\assets\icons\sort_incr.png'></img>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select formControlName="sortBySecond" id="soSort" class="custom-select">
        <option *ngFor="let opt of selectOptions" value="{{opt.value}}">{{opt.display}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="checkbox"
             formControlName="optionSecond"
             data-onstyle="outline-warning"
             data-offstyle="outline-warning"
             data-toggle="switchbutton"
             checked data-onlabel="<img src='..\..\..\..\assets\icons\sort_decrease.png'></img>"
             data-offlabel="<img src='..\..\..\..\assets\icons\sort_incr.png'></img>"/>
    </div>

<!--    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>-->
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-cypru" (click)="onSubmit()">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it will be much easier to help you if you create a stackblitz!

Comment: I'll do that and update my post, thank you!

Comment: turns out creating a stackblizz of this is quite hard since it is a big project with lots of dependencies... i'll try my best

Comment: The point of making a reproducible example is to narrow down the problem to as few code as possible. You can get rid of all dependencies that are unrelated to the problem.